# Ubuntu keeps on using internet time instead of RTC time

Tags: suspend, time, rtc

How do I make Ubuntu use the RTC time as the operating system time instead of waiting for my internet to connect to update the time? When my PC wakes from the sleep state, Ubuntu displays the old time (when the PC was put to sleep) for several seconds before updating it to the current local time. I would like to stop ubuntu from using the network time as it's operating system time and instead rely completely on the RTC time. However, I don't have this issue in Windows 10 because it uses its RTC time as its OS time and updates the RTC time when there are events like daylight savings). I'm aware of the "timedatectl set-local-rtc 1" command but that is not my issue. Thanks!

- Output for inxi -G command:
  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yd01.png)

Comment: Ubuntu/Linux uses your RTC clock. Always. This seems to be a glich in you graphical representation. This might indicate that you do not have the correct graphics drivers installed. What does `inxi-G` say? Please **edit** your question (use that little link below it) and paste the info from the terminal into your question.

Comment: I've updated my post with the output of the "inxi -G" command you've mentioned. Yes, I agree with you. I also think it is a drivers issue too because sometimes the audio doesn't work when my PC wakes up from the sleep state, but it works fine in Windows 10. Restarting Ubuntu fixes these issues but the problems occur again after a while. However, I'm not sure how to fix this issue. Also, Software Updater doesn't mention any updates to my PC.

Comment: Thanks, next time just copy the output from the terminal (Select-right click-context menu-Copy) and paste it directly into your question. See my answer for details

Comment: I delete my answer, since it was not thoroughly investigated , ChanganAuto pointed out:
 `radeon and amdgpu are different drivers for different AMD cards, the former for very old cards/chips (like the OP's) and the latter only for newer ones.`